# Arranging the Dataset in R as per Sum value

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, plyr

Please run the R code below, I wish to obtain a data set using this data below in which I have the "Brand" and "Candy" Column values appear once and corresponding time value to be the sum of all such cases. For illustration, I want the first two values "Mars" and "A" to appear only once and their sum "22" in the next column. Similarly for the rest, also the command should be fast to work on large data. Thanks and please help.

```
PlanetData <- read.table(
text = "
Brand       Candy                time
Mars        A                    10
Mars        A                    12
Jupiter     B                    13     
Jupiter     B                    14 
Saturn      C                    21
Saturn      C                    26",          
header = TRUE,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: `aggregate(PlanetData$time, list(PlanetData$Brand, PlanetData$Candy), sum)`

Comment: @LAP, Thanks for the help. However, will the command work fast on large data.

Comment: u try it out @RobertJ and if not you learn about parallel programming :-)

Comment: How large is your data? 50k rows or 30 million rows?

Comment: @LAP, It may be in millions

Answer (score 1):

You can try two alternative processes, using `dplyr` or `data.table` and pick the fastest one:

```
PlanetData <- read.table(
  text = "
  Brand       Candy                time
  Mars        A                    10
  Mars        A                    12
  Jupiter     B                    13     
  Jupiter     B                    14 
  Saturn      C                    21
  Saturn      C                    26",          
  header = TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(dplyr)

PlanetData %>% group_by(Brand, Candy) %>% summarise(SUM = sum(time)) %>% ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Brand   Candy   SUM
#   <chr>   <chr> <int>
# 1 Jupiter B        27
# 2 Mars    A        22
# 3 Saturn  C        47


library(data.table)

setDT(PlanetData)[, .(SUM=sum(time)),by=.(Brand, Candy)]

#       Brand Candy SUM
# 1:    Mars     A  22
# 2: Jupiter     B  27
# 3:  Saturn     C  47
```

It would be also useful to try the `dplyr` version using `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. It's very likely to be (slightly?) faster. It depends on how many rows and unique values you have.

*Note* that the moment you use `setDT(PlanetData)` then `PlanetData` becomes a `data.table` and not a `data.frame`. Make sure that doesn't skew/affect your timings when you go back to run the `dplyr` versions.